# PDFBox v3.0.0 StackOverflowError when splitting PDF file

Tags: java, stack-overflow, pdfbox

I have a Java class `Split` that is responsible for splitting PDF files into multiple parts based on page ranges. The class uses PDFBox for this purpose. Additionally, I have a `PDFModel` class to manage the resulting PDF files and a `Range` class to specify page ranges.

Here's the `Split` class:

```java
public class Split{
    private Logger logger;
    private File inputFile;
    private PDFModel pdfModel;
    private File outputDirectory;

    public Split(Logger logger, File inputFile, File outputDirectory) {
        // Constructor logic...
    }

    /**
     * Splits a PDF file based on a list of page ranges and saves the resulting partial PDFs.
     *
     * @param ranges A list of page ranges specifying which pages to split from the input PDF.
     * @return An ArrayList of PDFModel objects representing the resulting partial PDFs.
     */
    public ArrayList<PDFModel> splitByRanges(ArrayList<Range> ranges){
        ArrayList<PDFModel> results = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < ranges.size(); i++) {
            PDDocument partial = split(ranges.get(i));
            
            if(partial == null) {
                continue;
            }
            
            File outputFile = new File(Paths.get(outputDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "file_" + i + ".pdf").toString());
            
            try {
                partial.save(outputFile);
                results.add(new PDFModel(outputFile, partial));
                
                logger.info(this, "Successfully splitted '" + inputFile + "' from page " + ranges.get(i).getFrom() + " to " + ranges.get(i).getTo() + " into '" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'");  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        return results;
    }

    private PDDocument split(Range range) {
        PDDocument result = new PDDocument();

        int fromPage = range.getFrom();
        int toPage = range.getTo();
        
         // Get the PDPageTree from the PDDocument
        PDPageTree pdPageTree = pdfModel.getPDDocument().getPages();
        
        if (fromPage <= 0 || toPage <= 0 || fromPage > toPage || toPage > pdPageTree.getCount()) {
            logger.warning(this, "Invalid page range for splitting.");
            return null;
        }
        
        for (int i = range.getFrom() -1; i < range.getTo(); i++) {
            result.addPage(pdPageTree.get(i));
        }
        
        return result;
    }

}
```

The `org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter` does the same but doesn't work either.

```java
private PDDocument split(Range range) {
    int fromPage = range.getFrom();
    int toPage = range.getTo() ;

    PDDocument pddocument = pdfModel.getPDDocument();

    Splitter splitter = new Splitter();

    splitter.setStartPage(fromPage);
    splitter.setEndPage(toPage);
    splitter.setSplitAtPage(toPage - fromPage +1 );

    List<PDDocument> lst = null;
    
    try {
        lst = splitter.split(pddocument);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lst.get(0);
}
```

The `PDFModel` class:

```java
public class PDFModel {
    private File file;
    private PDDocument pdDocument;
    private ArrayList<PDFImage> images;
    private ArrayList<String> pages;

    public PDFModel(File file, PDDocument pdDocument) {
        // Constructor logic...
    }
}
```

The `Range` class:

```java
public class Range {
    private int from;
    private int to;

    public Range(int from, int to) {
        // Constructor logic...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this `Split` class to split a PDF file into multiple parts using the following code:

This throws an error:

```java
Splitter splitter = new Splitter(logger, inputFile, outputDirectory);
splitter.splitByRanges(new ArrayList<Range>(Arrays.asList(new Range(1, 7), new Range(8, 9), new Range(10, 11)));
```

And this works perfectly fine (not for `org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter`):

```java
Splitter splitter = new Splitter(logger, inputFile, outputDirectory);
splitter.splitByRanges(new ArrayList<Range>(Arrays.asList(new Range(1, 8), new Range(10, 12), new Range(14, 16)));
```

However, I'm encountering the following StackOverflowError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.tableSizeFor(HashMap.java:378)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:455)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:439)
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:171)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:167)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.SmallMap.entrySet(SmallMap.java:384)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary.entrySet(COSDictionary.java:1232)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.compress.COSWriterObjectStream.writeCOSDictionary(COSWriterObjectStream.java:338)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.compress.COSWriterObjectStream.writeObject(COSWriterObjectStream.java:232)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.compress.COSWriterObjectStream.writeCOSDictionary(COSWriterObjectStream.java:343)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.compress.COSWriterObjectStream.writeObject(COSWriterObjectStream.java:232)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.compress.COSWriterObjectStream.writeCOSArray(COSWriterObjectStream.java:321)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.compress.COSWriterObjectStream.writeObject(COSWriterObjectStream.java:228)
```

### Question

How can I resolve this StackOverflow error?

Comment: That stack trace doesn't look like a full track. Can you provide the full stack trace of the error and the error description from the trace?

Comment: @M.Rizzo I've added the full stack, hope that helps.

Comment: What version of PDFBox are you currently using?

Comment: @M.Rizzo I'm using org.apache.pdfbox version 3.0.0

Comment: I thought this may an issue with the COSDictionary and handling page recursion between parent and children, but that issue was addressed in 3.0.0.  I'm not sure what the cause could be here.

Comment: Please share the source file

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I solved the issue by avoiding the step of copying pages from the original document into a new `PDDocument`. Instead, I'm directly using the `PDDocument` I've loaded from my file, and this works perfectly fine. But now there is an issue with reusing the `PDDocument`, I would need an approach to clone it and then make the changes.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've provided my solution, but the approach is not very straigh forward. Hope you have some suggestions for improvment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a problem in your code. Btw there's a nasty bug in 3.0.0, call `targetDoc.getDocument().setHighestXRefObjectNumber(sourceDoc.getDocument().getHighestXRefObjectNumber());` or save with the uncompressed option. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5696 Also make sure not to close the source document before you've saved all the destination documents.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you for your assistance! I'm pleased to inform you that it's working as expected with PDFBox v2.0.29.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The resolved issue suggests it should be fixed in v3.0.1, but there's no stable release available for maven at the moment. I really need some functionality from v3. Do you have any information on a release date or any temporary workarounds?

Comment: Please don't post solutions in a **question**, post them as an **answer**. Also make sure your question actually asks a question.

Comment: You can try a snapshot: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ However the fixed issue wasn't about a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

The problem seems to be on `pdfbox`'s side so here just a workaround for version 3.0.0

```java
private PDDocument split(Range range) {
    PDDocument pdDocument = new PDDocument();
    
    for (PDPage pdPage : pdfModel.getPDDocument().getPages()) {
        pdDocument.addPage(pdPage);
    }
    
    int fromPage = range.getFrom();
    int toPage = range.getTo();
    
    int pageCount = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();

    if (fromPage > 0 && toPage > 0 && pageCount >= fromPage && pageCount < toPage) {
        logger.warning(this, "Invalid page range for splitting.");
        return null;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Page count: " + pdDocument.getNumberOfPages());
            
    for (int n = pageCount - 1; n >= toPage; n--) {
        pdDocument.removePage(n);
    }
    
    for (int n = fromPage -2; n >= 0; n--) {
        pdDocument.removePage(n);
    }
    
    return pdDocument;
}
```

## Solution 2

Use `org.apache.pdfbox` version > `3.0.0` or a later version `3.0.1` and above hopfully [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5696) resolves the bug.